# How to choose collation for SQL Azure IAAS

Tags: sql-server, azure, json

We are trying to define a parametric IAAS SQL Server setup.
But we require a different collation than the default sql_latin01_general_cp1_ci_as.

I can't seem to find it in the json template / parameter or as a parameter in the Powershell.

Is there a way to define a different collation when setting up a IAAS SQL Server for Azure?

Comment: What do you mean of `collation`. If my understanding is right, you want to classify the database, you could use use [tags](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-using-tags) to organize your SQL server.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT What I mean by collation, is the default collation of the SQL Server instance that comes pre-installed with the Windows server. The reason we need to be able to define this dynamically is because we support a variety of applications. Some of which such as the version of Citrix our supplier supports require a specific collation.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT So I'm talking about [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK You can't change the collation when provisioning a IaaS from the SQL Server Image.  It comes with SQL pre-loaded and there is no way to change this during the deployment process.  The media and key are located on the server, so the steps would be the following

1. Create SQL Server VM From IaaS Sql Server Template
2. Uninstall SQL
3. Re-install SQL with the collation you want

Comment: This is what I also came to think, and fear. I'll leave the question open for a while to see if anyone can prove us wrong. If not that is very unfortunate and removes a part of the flexibility of IAAS SQL Server on Azure for larger enterprises. +1

Comment: I got confirmation from M$ in an Azure ticket, that it is indeed impossible. They however recommend rebuilding the master database. Perhaps something you would like to add to your answer.